# Reactjs - How to add 1 item to array per second by using Hook useEffect and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

```
/**
   * init array: [1, 2]
   * Expect
   * array per 1s: [1, 2, 3]
   * array per 2s: [1, 2, 3, 4]
   * array per (n)s: [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n]
   */
  const [countList, setCountList] = useState([]);
  const counter = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter.current = counter.current + 1;
      setCountList([...countList, counter.current]);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>{countList.map((count) => count + ',')}</div>
    </>
  );
```

I want every second, the array to push 1 item and then display that on UI but the array only updates the last item. Exp [1, 2] => [1, 3] => [1, 4] ...

Comment: It works perfect for me. What's the problem ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-water-dmuuys

Comment: I think something went wrong but the code sandbox is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to just set the interval once on mount, not set and clear it repeatedly. Sort of defeats the purpose of setting an interval. You need to use a callback function to get the previous value, and pass an empty dependency array to useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter.current = counter.current + 1;
      setCountList((prev) => [...prev, counter.current]);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1rt29v?file=App.tsx

Comment: Greate explain. I applied it too

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You have to regenerate the `interval` when `countList` was updated.

```
  const [countList, setCountList] = React.useState([]);
  const counter = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter.current = counter.current + 1;

      setCountList([...countList, counter.current]);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [countList]);
```

Comment: Another one should ref the above comment by @Chris